# How to transmit a tv channels to the Internet/mobile app?

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, live-streaming

My partner is owner of a local channel tv and he wants an mobile app with the streaming of his tv channel. How could I start?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a complicated end to end system you require - one simple first question is whether his channel is already broadcast by an existing broadcaster over satellite etc? If so you may find they already have an OTT (internet based delivery) option.

Assuming not then you have several key components:

- video source - i.e. the live stream from the channel
- some sort of streaming server to convert the video source into the formats required to stream over the internet. Take a look at Wowza as an example of a paid solution of videoLAN as an open source solution.
- the mobile app - this will be slightly easier if you just have to stream from one channel.
- some sort of user registration and programme guide / search backend if required.

You may also require a DRM solution if you need to protect the content against unauthorised playback, copying etc.